# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str, working with optparse module

Tags: python, typeerror

```
import subprocess
import optparse

def change_mac(interface, new_mac):
    print("[+] Changing MAC address for " + interface + " to " + new_mac)

    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "hw", "ether ", new_mac])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "up"])


parser = optparse.OptionParser()

parser.add_option( "-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="interface to change its MAC address")
parser.add_option( "-m", "--mac", dest="new_mac", help="new MAC address")

(options, arguments) = parser.parse_args()
change_mac(options.interface, options.new_mac)
```

this is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    change_mac(options.interface, options.new_mac)
  File "main.py", line 7, in change_mac
    print("[+] Changing MAC address for " + interface + " to " + new_mac)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

I'm aware of Python Basics and ive done a few programs before this , I was following a course and the guy made this exact program but he isnt getting errors, I am. If somebody could help me understand the problem it would be really helpful cuz i dont want to progress further into the course without fixing this.

Comment: Are you passing in command line arguments when you run this?

Comment: yes i am, in Kali linux and i get the same error

Comment: Show exactly how you're running this, because not starting the program correctly seems like the most likely reason.

Comment: https://imgur.com/rmJUQ6P.png , is this what u are asking for? sorry im kinda new

Comment: The error in your screen shot doesn't match the error in the title.

Comment: I'm sorry, i wasnt sure i first sent the error from the program which i ran in the IDE and then u made me realise i should try it in command line and it gave me different errors, i will change my title, im new to stack overflow

Comment: I seems like you should make these arguments [required](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#required)...

Comment: Wait, the new problem is because of Kali iirc. `ifconfig` is deprecated and was removed from the PATH. You're supposed to use `ip` instead; although it's an entirely different syntax. If you `updatedb; locate ifconfig`, you can find the old binary, and add that location to the PATH.

Comment: i installed a net-tools package so that i should be able to use ifconfig instead of ip.

Comment: Can you use `ifconfig` in the terminal outside of Pycharm? Have you restarted Pycharm since installing `net-tools`?

Comment: yes i can use ifconfig in the terminal, and when i had only used the subprocess module to make a  MAC address changer script ifconfig was working, only after using the optparse module ive started getting errors

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding default values to those options:

```
parser.add_option( "-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="interface to change its MAC address", default="interface not provided")
parser.add_option( "-m", "--mac", dest="new_mac", help="new MAC address", default="mac address not provided")
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate you are right, I've suggested the use of default.

Comment: That still doesn't look like a good idea. Now you're just passing a weird string to `ifconfig`... It seems to make more sense to make those arguments required (not optional)...

Comment: i got more errors after trying this, now i am not even sure if i understand :(

Comment: https://imgur.com/LrAXwAm.png , these are the errors

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def change_mac(interface, new_mac):
    interface = interface or '' # instead of empty string you can set a value
    new_mac = new_mac or '' # instead of empty string you can set a value
    print("[+] Changing MAC address for " , interface , " to " , new_mac)
```

Or you can have default value in the method's definition

```
def change_mac(interface='some_value', new_mac='Some Value'):
    print("[+] Changing MAC address for " , interface , " to " , new_mac)
```